# Given positive integers a and b, find values for a and b if a! * b! = a! + b!

Tags: factorial

Given positive integers a and b, find values for a and b if a! * b! = a! + b!

I have no clue where to start and would appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: Hint: divide both sides by $\min\{a,b\}!$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first show that if $a,b>2$ then $ab>a+b$. 
$a+b-ab=a+b-ab-1+1=1-(1-a)(1-b)<0$ since $1-a<-1$ and $1-b<-1$. This imply that there no solutions when $a!,b!>2$. We thus have only two cases to consider, $a,b=1,2$

Case $a=b=1$ and $(a,b)=(1,2)$ provides no solution. Only the case $a=b=2$ gives a solution.

Comment: I'm not too sure on why that implies there are no solutions when a!,b! > 2

Comment: Because $a!b!>a!+b!$

Answer (score 1):

If $a!\cdot b!=a!+b!$ then
$$1=\frac{1}{a!}+\frac{1}{b!}$$
The only solution is $a=b=2$